# C#: Modify a text file on a network. Blocking function

Tags: c#

I'm not a very experienced programmer, so I'm wondering if my solution is a good one or if there is an easier way. Can you give me some feedback?

**The problem:**

I have multiple C# programs that are modifying a text file on a computer within a network. I need each program to open the file in such a way that, if a program tries to open the file while the file is already open in another program, it will wait until the file is closed.

**My solution:**

```
public void MainFunction(machineName, fileName, timeOut){ //Start here
    filePath = "\\\\" + machineName + "\\Users\\Public\\" + fileName + ".txt";
    FileStream file = GetFile(filePath, timeOut); // See below
    ModifyFile(file) //This function is unique to every program
    file.Close();
    return;
}

// Block the program until the file opens or you reach the timeout limit
public FileStream GetFile(string fileName, int timeOut){ // Recursive function
    FileStream file = null;
    try{

        file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        return file; // Success!

    }catch (IOException ex){    // File was already open

        if (timeOut > 0){
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            file = GetFile(fileName, (timeOut - 1)); // Recursively call this function
        }
        if (file != null){      // Got file before timeout
            return file;
        }else{                  // Timeout
            throw ex;
        }

    }catch (Exception ex){      // Something else went wrong

        throw ex;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, *why* are you trying to do this? An interesting question though, exceptions are not a great way of tracking this kind of thing but it may be your only choice.

Comment: Use the Microsoft Office way: write a lock file in the same folder of the real file when you open it, then remove it when you're done. Don't open the file if the lock file exists.

Comment: This is pretty stupid I'm afraid. File system access isn't optimised for multi-user systems.

Comment: Why not have an application that the other programs communicate with which in turn writes to the file? Then you can manage the synchronization in that program instead.

Comment: @Default It might be more secure/efficient, but definitely isn't easier. To quote the OP: "I'm not a very experienced programmer".

Comment: @Kroltan Thanks. That sounds like a much better way.